# CodeIgniter : How to set a value on the edit page

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, undefined-index

I want to make an edit form , but I have a problem when displaying the data . This is a warning in my code ..

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: pakar_username
>
> Filename: m_pakar/edit_pakar.php
>
> Line Number: 20

This is my view:

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="<?=base_url()?>admin/m_pakar/edit_pakar?>">
  <label>Username</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $coba['pakar_username']?>" ><br>
  <label>Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $coba['pakar_password']?>"><br>
  <label>Email</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $coba['pakar_email']?>" ><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
```

My Controller:

```
public function edit_pakar($id){

    $this->general->set_table('data_pakar');
    $this->general->order('pakar_id', 'asc');

    $datasend['coba'] = $this->general->get_result_array();

    $datasave = array(
            'pakar_username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
            'pakar_password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE)),
            'pakar_email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
    );

    $this->general->set_table('data_pakar');
    $this->general->where($datasave);

    $this->general->update($datasave);
    $dataview['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/m_pakar/edit_pakar', $datasend, TRUE);
    $this->load->view($this->template, $dataview);

}
```

> Is there something wrong with my code ? not only pakar_username , but all existing data on the edit form doesn't show.

Comment: Is `general` some kind of custom database library?

Comment: Can you show us the code behind this function: `$this->general->get_result_array();`?

Comment: @PinoyPal this my function: `public function get_result_array() {

        $get = $this->db->get($this->tbname);

        if($get->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $get->result_array();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }`

There is nothing wrong in my code ?

Comment: Since you used `return $get->result_array()` would return an array of records not a single row, you should change it to `return $get->row_array()` so you can use `$coba['pakar_username']` otherwise you will have to use `$coba[n]['pakar_username']` where `n` represents an index of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you got all this bloated code in your controller? Move the Database stuff to a model...

HTML Form Fix:

```
<form method="post" role="form" action="<?=base_url()?>admin/m_pakar/edit_pakar">
```

Secondly, you're not pushing the details in "datasave" to the view, you're only pushing "datasend", so I adjusted for "coba2" incase you need coba...

```
$datasend['coba'] = $this->general->get_result_array();

$datasave = array(
        'pakar_username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
        'pakar_password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE)),
        'pakar_email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
);

$datasend['coba2'] = $datasave;
```

Now edit input fields as so:

```
value="<?php echo $coba2['pakar_username']?>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this code not work in my web ..
i have problem in 'input fields' ..

Comment: Give me a chance and I'll look over it again and get back to you.

Comment: thanks before..
I want to edit a data, but when I select the data . blank ( not showing anything ) , there is nothing wrong in `value="<?php echo $coba2['pakar_username']?>"` ?